# Three.js - why does textured Points system appear only on some systems?

Tags: three.js

I would like to use the three.js Points (formerly PointCloud) object to display textured sprites using the WebGLRenderer.  This is supposed to be much more efficient than adding each sprite individually.  However, sprites generated this way don't show up on my computer.  They do show up on my phone, however.

Combinations that work on my computer:

- Sprite with SpriteMaterial.
- Points with PointsMaterial where the map element in the input parameter is not set. Example from three.js site: [points / dynamic](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_points_dynamic)

The combination that doesn't work:

- Points with PointsMaterial, where the input map element is set to a Texture. Example: [points / billboards](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_points_billboards)

I get the same behavior with code from a three.js textbook.  The computer that won't display the Points is an old MacBook running Mac OS X 10.6.8 and Chrome 44.0.2403.107.  The phone that will display them is an iPhone 4s running iOS 8.1.

Questions:

- any idea what hardware or software feature prevents the textured Points sprites from showing up?
- is there any way to detect whether a user's browser will be able to display textured Points?

Comment: do the textures have size of powers of 2?

Comment: Yes, always, though I did that by accident.  Does it matter to some systems?

Comment: Another piece of data: Chrome stopped running WebGL for me after updating (when I went to check the version).  I can run in Safari or Firefox though, and the behavior is exactly the same as what I had in Chrome.  Suggests a hardware issue, i.e. what features work on my integrated GPU.

Comment: WebGL on Mac shares some components between all browsers. Crash for one, all are dead. Reboot.

Comment: I have...doesn't help.